# hibernate @DynamicUpdate() with @UpdateTimestamp can't work ,how can i do?

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate()
@DynamicInsert()
public class User  {
  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Timestamp updatedAt;
}
```

but updatedAt is not work,only DynamicUpdate(false) can work,how to do ite

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using Spring Data JPA, try using the `@LastModifiedBy` annotation.

1. Annotate the field, with `@LastModifiedBy`

   ```
   @Column(name = "modified_by")
   @LastModifiedBy
   private String modifiedBy;`
   ```
2. Set the Auditing Listener on the entity, with `@EntityListeners`

   ```
   @Entity
   @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
   public class Bar {
      ...
   }
   ```
3. Enable JPA Auditing on your configuration with `@EnableJpaAuditing`

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableJpaAuditing
   public class ExampleConfig{
      ...
   }
   ```

References:

http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/support/AuditingEntityListener.html